# SQL - Get custom day start datetime for passed datetime

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I am working on requirement where the day starts at 23:00 last day. 
I need to get day start date time for passed date to SQL function. We are storing custom day start time (i.e. 23:00) and `offset = -1` (means starting last day) in table now.
e.g. If I pass :

1. `10/30/2013 22:00` it should return `10/29/2013 23:00`
2. `10/30/2013 23:20` it should return `10/30/2013 23:00`
3. `10/31/2013 01:00` it should return `10/30/2013 23:00`

Currently I am using following statement : `(DayStartOffset = -1 and DayStartTime = 23:00:00)`

```
    declare @datetime datetime 
    set @datetime = '2013-10-30 23:59:59'
    declare @date date
    declare @time time(3)
    set @date = @datetime
    set @time = @datetime
    declare @dayStartDateTime datetime 

    --DayStartOffset is set to -1
    --DayStartTime set to '23:00'
    SELECT @dayStartDateTime = DATEADD(dd,DayStartOffset,CAST(@date AS DATETIME)) +                 CAST(DayStartTime AS DATETIME)
     from table_name
     print @dayStartDateTime
```

But it is not working correctly for e.g. 1 and 3 above

Can you please help me on this function.

Comment: Which version of sql server are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In one line

```
Create Function dbo.MyStartOfDay(@datetime datetime) returns datetime as
begin
    return dateadd(hour, -1, dateadd(day, datediff(day, 0, dateadd(hour, 1, @datetime)), 0))
end
Go
Select dbo.MyStartOfDay('2013-10-30 22:00');
```

Broken down

```
Create Function dbo.MyStartOfDay(@datetime datetime) returns datetime as
begin
    declare @hourLater datetime = dateadd(hour, 1, @datetime)
    declare @roundToDay datetime = dateadd(day, datediff(day, 0, @hourLater), 0);
    declare @hourBack datetime = dateadd(hour, -1, @roundToDay)
    return @hourBack
end
```

In other words, add an hour on, round down to the nearest day then take an hour off.

**<kbd>[Example SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9d970/1)</kbd>**